# Visual Studio Git Push Specific Outgoing Commits

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-push, team-explorer

I made several code changes and then committed them to my local repo from (Changes) in Visual Studio Team Explorer. Once I committed the changes to my local, all of the commits were automatically listed in the (Synchronization) Outgoing Commits. However, I only intend to Push some, not all of the commits to the remote repo. How do I remove any items from the list that I do not intend to Push OR select only the items I intend to Push? Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with the other changes? Do you want to keep them locally or discard them?

Comment: I would like to keep them locally. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In `git` each commit points to its parent, which then points to its parent, and so on until you reach the first commit ever.

So, if you have this local branch:

```
myBranch           o--A--X--B--Y--C--Z
```

But you only want to push commits `XYZ` to the `remote` to get:

```
remote/myBranch    o--X--Y--Z
```

This isn't possible. Commit `Z` has the parent `C`, it can't have the parent `Y`.

---

**Let's do it anyways**

I know I just said it isn't possible, but we can do something very close.

Starting from this structure:

```
master      o
             \
myBranch      A--X--B--Y--C--Z
```

We want to separate `ABC` and `XYZ`, push `XYZ` to the remote, and keep `ABC` locally.

1. `git checkout myBranch` - Switch to the current branch with everything on it
2. `git branch -b myBranch-old` - Create a copy of the original state of the branch
3. `git log` - List commits starting from the most recent. Note down the full commit ids for each of the commits
4. `git reset --hard master` - Reset `myBranch` to before any changes were applied (note: if you do not have a convenient branch here, you can use the appropriate commit id from above)
5. `git cherry-pick X` - Copy commit `X` into the current branch
6. `git cherry-pick Y` - Copy commit `Y` into the current branch
7. `git cherry-pick Z` - Copy commit `Z` into the current branch
8. `git push --force` - Push the current changes to the remote. The `--force` is necessary because we are rewriting history

Current state:

```
master                o
                      |\
myBranch (and remote) \ X`-Y`-Z`
                       \
myBranch-old            A--X--B--Y--C--Z
```

Now reapply the other changes.

9. `git cherry-pick A` - Copy commit `A` into the current branch
10. `git cherry-pick B` - Copy commit `B` into the current branch
11. `git cherry-pick C` - Copy commit `C` into the current branch

Final state:

```
master                o
                      |\
remote/myBranch       | X`-Y`-Z`
                      |        \
myBranch              \         A`-B`-C`
                       \
myBranch-old            A--X--B--Y--C--Z
```

Now delete `myBranch-old` and everything is done.

---

**But that's crazy!**

Yes it is. The bottom line is that you shouldn't mingle unrelated changes like this. Branches are your friend. Make more branches. In `git`, unlike `TFS` or `SVN`, branches are almost free - both in terms of storage and processing. In fact, the cost is so low I don't worry about the number of branches in the team repository until it's pushing 1000. Even then, the concern is more about reading through that many branches rather than actual performance impact.

I don't know how you got into the situation the prompted this question, but the fix is always going to be the same: **New task = new branch. Always**

Comment: But if I want to push all Outgoing commits except the last one? Is it possible to do in Visual Studio?

Comment: @Vitaliy I used `git push origin HEAD~1:branchname` for this. There are probably multiple other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in thinking that commits are individual things that can be dealt with one at a time.

You are incorrect in thinking that a commit represents a single set of changes. A commit is a complete copy of the source code. It's easiest to think of a commit as a zipped up snapshot of your source folder, because that's basically exactly what it is. When you "view" a commit, you're actually viewing a diff of a commit and it's parent commit, which is what developers usually want to see.

However, the good news is that you can use a git command called "cherry-pick" to select that diff and attempt to create a new commit with a different history that applies just those changes.

In your case, it sounds like you'll want to create a new branch based off the server, then cherry-pick the commits that you care about and then push that branch to the server.